# How to trace a Internal Ether Send

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, rpc, internal-transactions

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to track the ETH Sent internally from a contract.
Specifically https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e2ef793b4fd7ffa968d49d94c7bab63434eeb9a68572a81f469a4ab8c974d06
you See 2 trnxs Sent using interal functions.

I am Running a Full Archive Node and am using getBlockWithTransactions and then passing each  transactionion to debug_traceTransaction.
I then have access to the struct logs But I am not sure what to look for in here?
is it op:CALL or op:DELEGATECALL?
and then once I find these where should I be looking to retrieve the exact ETH sent?

any help on this would be appreciated!

I am using web3 and ethers in a nodeJS program.

one example of return data for op:CALL is

```
 pc: 5818,
  op: 'CALL',
  gas: 151912,
  gasCost: 149540,
  depth: 2,
  stack: [
    '0x357a150b',
    '0x179',
    '0x80',
    '0x470de4df820000',
    '0x0',
    '0x4a0',
    '0x180',
    '0xbda',
    '0x180',
    '0x6a0',
    '0x4a0',
    '0x0',
    '0x470de4df820000',
    '0x380',
    '0x9aac977eb7befddab7d9c18bf5f203e3f2e0001f2f0c92fc8fc97a4e9d521e0e',
    '0x3c0',
    '0xf849de01b080adc3a814fabe1e2087475cf2e354',
    '0xbc553f0f',
    '0x1140',
    '0x20',
    '0x103c',
    '0x104',
    '0x103c',
    '0x0',
    '0xf849de01b080adc3a814fabe1e2087475cf2e354',
    '0x25168'
  ],
  memory: [
    '9aac977eb7befddab7d9c18bf5f203e3f2e0001f2f0c92fc8fc97a4e9d521e0e',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cb',
    '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000103c',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000460',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006a0',
    'e06c6594c92e8770af14b20ea2f2fe2400acf089a733d62a04a817f27e3f29f1',
    '4a13bd0ceb13aa7f7966fd8db59d8210865459c23e3465630759f09872eb8fb4',
    '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180',
    '000000000000000000000000000000003d196e032a8accc8343a51ba24c9e7f9',
    '000000000000000000000000e19dd424421c80b4df397c5dde08588f2536466b',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063187329',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000320',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000340',
    '1fbf0cac9d56772e8c398d2c2353ad3320dcf6845d1fa325aa8b66000a5fbcc5',
    '1cf9be6ef3637a7e5a365318f74a9b0478fdcf058c932cf124a59d57235b165d',
    '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000380',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000470de4df820000',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c0',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000007946c4bededc2ab98e1682c55505093c88624c02',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c84',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004a0',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000470de4df820000',
    '9aac977eb7befddab7d9c18bf5f203e3f2e0001f2f0c92fc8fc97a4e9d521e0e',
    '000000000000000000000000f849de01b080adc3a814fabe1e2087475cf2e354',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000620',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000660',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001388',
    '000000000000000000000000d823c605807cc5e6bd6fc0d7e4eea50d3e2d66cd',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003de9459e5313e',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063174d03',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000004849772b5cabda639562dec7a6050dd5cb0fe461',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000320',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003de9459e5313e',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063174d03',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000004849772b5cabda639562dec7a6050dd5cb0fe461',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000470de4df820000',
    '9aac977eb7befddab7d9c18bf5f203e3f2e0001f2f0c92fc8fc97a4e9d521e0e',
    '000000000000000000000000f849de01b080adc3a814fabe1e2087475cf2e354',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001388',
    '000000000000000000000000d823c605807cc5e6bd6fc0d7e4eea50d3e2d66cd',
    '00000000000000000000000067e237e728b7e2404db9f460711e8caca70571c4',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280',
    '000000000000000000000000000000003d196e032a8accc8343a51ba24c9e7f9',
    '000000000000000000000000e19dd424421c80b4df397c5dde08588f2536466b',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063187329',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020',
    ... 38 more items
  ]
```

I then have no Idea where to ifnd that info in here....

Thanks for all your assistance here!

Answer (score 2):

When looking at opcodes you go to the stack to see the input. [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/) is a good resource. So in the example you posted we see the CALL opcode. CALL has 7 inputs which get popped off the stack in order. So:

1. gas : 0x25168 (151912 in decimals)
2. address : 0xf849de01b080adc3a814fabe1e2087475cf2e354
3. value : 0x0
4. argsOffset : 0x103c
5. argsSize : 0x104
6. retOffset : 0x103c
7. retSize : 0x20

Value is what you are looking here. In the above call 0 eth was sent to 0xf84..354.

CREATE, CREATE2 and CALLCODE are other opcodes that can also send eth.